# Infinite loop in a lambda, print only maximum values?

Tags: python

How can I cast an infinite loop in Python that would run an expression and print its value only if it is bigger than a previously saved value? I also want it to update the new maximum values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves the problem:

```
from __future__ import print_function #needed python 2.7 only


import random
example_expression = lambda: random.random()

a = [0]
b = [-1]

[ print(a[0]) 
  for i in iter(int,1) #causes an infinite loop
  if  not a.__setitem__(0,example_expression()) #__setitem__ will return None 
  and a[0]>b[0] 
  and not b.__setitem__(0,a[0])  ]
```

Comment: You cooked this one up pretty fast ;-P

Comment: `example_expression()` should be `some_expression()`